# visual studio project always rebuilding but pdb not updated

Tags: visual-studio

I've turned on verbose logging.

I'm always getting this:

```
1>FastUpToDate: Input 'C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.ODBC\obj\project.assets.json' is newer (5/5/2020 8:52:58 AM) than earliest output 'C:\Development\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Bentley.APM.Common.ODBC.pdb' (5/1/2020 11:17:23 PM), not up to date. (Bentley.APM.Common.ODBC)
```

In the bin folder the dlls timestamp gets updated every time I build.
But the corresponding pdb timestamp is from DAYS ago.

I think the pdb is only getting updated if I go and manually edit one of the files inside the project that keeps "rebuilding".

Here is some more output that looks somewhat concerning:

```
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Ivara.ServiceProvider.Interoperability\Ivara.ServiceProvider.Interoperability.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'common\Authentication\Bentley.APM.Authentication.Oidc.Client\Bentley.APM.Authentication.Oidc.Client.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'common\Authentication\Bentley.APM.Authentication.SSPI\Bentley.APM.Authentication.SSPI.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'common\Authentication\Bentley.APM.Authentication.Interfaces\Bentley.APM.Authentication.Interfaces.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'common\Authentication\Bentley.APM.Authentication.Common\Bentley.APM.Authentication.Common.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'common\IvaraCommon\IvaraCommon.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Bentley.APM.ServiceProvider.GraphQL\Bentley.APM.ServiceProvider.GraphQL.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Rest.Common\Rest.Common.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Ivara.ServiceProvider.Interoperability\Test\Ivara.ServiceProvider.Interoperability.Test.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Bentley.APM.ServiceProvider.GraphQL\Tests\Bentley.APM.ServiceProvider.GraphQL.Tests.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Bentley.APM.ServiceProvider.GraphQL\UnitTests\Bentley.APM.ServiceProvider.GraphQL.UnitTests.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Rest.Common.Tests\Rest.Common.Tests.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Ivara.ServiceProvider.MobileRestService\UnitTests\Ivara.ServiceProvider.MobileRestService.UnitTests.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Ivara.ServiceProvider.MobileRestService\Test\Ivara.ServiceProvider.MobileRestService.Test.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Utilities\ServiceProviderHost\ServiceProviderHost.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'TestingInfrastructure\TestConfigurationApp\TestSettings.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'TestingInfrastructure\TestFramework\TestFramework.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at VSLangProj80.Reference3.get_SourceProject()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VsCoreProjectSystemReferenceReader.IsProjectReference(Reference3 reference, ILogger logger)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at VSLangProj80.Reference3.get_SourceProject()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VsCoreProjectSystemReferenceReader.IsProjectReference(Reference3 reference, ILogger logger)
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'EXPLink\EXPLinkTestSuiteExtensions\EXPLinkTestSuiteExtensions.vcxproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Failed to resolve all items referenced by 'Service Providers\Ivara.ServiceProvider.MobileRestService\Ivara.ServiceProvider.MobileRestService.csproj'. This message can typically be ignored. The issue may be resolved by fully restoring and building the solution. If the unresolved item is a project reference this can lead to an incomplete NuGet restore result and missing package references. To ensure that restore is able to find all projects verify that all projects are referenced correctly and exist on disk.
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Running restore with 12 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Extensions\Bentley.APM.Common.Extensions.csproj.
```

**Edit - I am back in this state again:**

```
1>FastUpToDate: Input 'C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging\obj\project.assets.json' is newer (5/13/2020 5:25:07 AM) than earliest output 'C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging\obj\x64\Release\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging.pdb' (5/11/2020 2:28:57 PM), not up to date. (Bentley.APM.Common.Logging)
1>------ Build started: Project: Bentley.APM.Common.Logging, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
1>  Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target CoreCompile:
1>  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
1>  Touching "C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging\obj\x64\Release\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging.csproj.CopyComplete".
1>Target ApmUpdateVersion:
1>  C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging\obj\x64\Release\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging.dll : Version resource updated
1>
```

This will keep building again and again with:

```
1>FastUpToDate: Input 'C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging\obj\project.assets.json' is newer (5/13/2020 5:25:07 AM) than earliest output 'C:\Development\Source\DotNet\common\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging\obj\x64\Release\Bentley.APM.Common.Logging.pdb' (5/11/2020 2:28:57 PM), not up to date. (Bentley.APM.Common.Logging)
```

The pdb is over two days old and doesn't seem to get updated.

I'm thinking that is because

```
1>Target CoreCompile: 1> Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

Comment: So what is the question or problem?

Comment: In visual studio the projects keep rebuilding.  To me it looks like it keeps rebuilding because the pdb is not up to date.  But the pdb never gets updated, the timestamp is from several days ago.  If I go to modify a file inside the project then the pdb gets updated.  But if I don't, every time I go to build the solution it will keep building a whole bunch of projects, but the project's pdb doesn't get updated.

Comment: _To me it looks like it keeps rebuilding because the pdb is not up to date._  -- I think you can prove or disprove this theory by disabling (temporarily) producing .pdb

Comment: Have you tried to change your Debug path and rebuilding it?

Comment: First of all why is this a problem? If source didn't change why should the *.pdb* change? Anyway, did you take the standard steps? 1: Delete the *.pdb* 2: restart *VStudio* and a full rebuild 3: Restart *Win* + step *#2.* 4: Delete *VStudio* solution metadata (a *vs* *dir* in the solution's *dir*)?

Comment: You have a fairly complicated environment there. Are you able to reproduce it with a smaller (dummy) *.csproj* (add it in the solution)? Could you post the *csproj* (if the dummy attempt isn't possible, then the *Logging* one) **and the *\*.target* file** (s)?

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution and rebuild or deleting the PDBs before building the solution should work

Answer (score -1):

Hello try delete this hidden folder .vs .Remove your reference, clean the bin folder and add the reference again.Then Run your program